# iTunes tracks are not playing or downloading from Purchased

Tags: itunes, music

After purchasing a new iMac computer, I naturally opened up iTunes and began to download my purchased music onto the machine. The process went smoothly enough, but I noticed that a few songs from an album that I had bought a few weeks ago weren't downloading correctly. The song would download, then iTunes would say "There was an error downloading the song", then I would have to redownload it from Purchased, which worked. But some of the songs, even though they downloaded fine after the second try, just simply won't play when I click on them. What I mean is that they show up in my Music Library, but they won't play when I double-click them, instead, the song will briefly show up in the Now Playing bar, then disappear as iTunes skips to the next song. Any advice? This might just be an isolated incident.

Comment: Try deleting and redownloading, perhaps? It's an obvious fix, but perhaps it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an Authorization issue since this is a new computer.

Open iTunes> In the menu bar select, "Authorize This Computer"> Enter your Apple ID credentials (linked with the purchases you are attempting to download) and click "Authorize".